# Is there a way to capture the collection of shell commands that fabric outputs?

Tags: python, bash, fabric, paramiko

I've got a collection of fab files that I use to manage servers, install applications on them etc for clients. Some of them are not very happy when I deliver install documentation as a fabfile and readme. There are usually experienced sysadmins, just not python programmers. If I could give them a bash script that is a record of what the various fabfiles did then that would be great. Does anyone know the best way to do this?

I don't need help to manually translate fab commands into bash. I'm looking for a programatic  way to capture the stream of commands, either from paramiko or fabric or on the remote host itself.

Comment: we might be able to help if you post a typical fab file. The one on the online documentation seems a little too simple to cover a usable solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> If I could give them a bash script that is a record of what the various fabfiles did then that would be great.

and later

> I don't need help to manually translate fab commands into bash. I'm looking for a programatic way to capture the stream of commands, either from paramiko or fabric or on the remote host itself.

It would really help to disambiguate your question to include sample fab file AND desired output.

That said, did you see this in the doc? I couldn't find a place where it is mentioned if COMMAND is a place holder or a literal, it would seem that is a place holder. (and I may be completely misinterpreting the intent of the option, fab documenters, more examples please! )

```
-d COMMAND, --display=COMMAND
Prints the entire docstring for the given task, if there is one. 
Does not currently print out the task’s function signature, 
so descriptive docstrings are a good idea. (They’re always a good idea,  
of course – just moreso here.)
```

But it sounds like you could get what you want by inserting the complete command into a docstring.

I hope this helps.